# PayPal payment integration for REACT NATIVE with latest lib android + ios

Tags: android, ios, paypal, react-native

Can any body provide a swipe solution with latest `react-native` PayPal library ?

I have spent a week but not getting a proper solution.

There are many old and incomplete solution on net but not a proper and
complete solution for new developers.

Resources :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paypal

https://github.com/MattFoley/react-native-paypal

https://github.com/sharafat/sample-code-php

Comment: After a long Research i found that currently PayPal does not support to SDK, Provided solution was worked with old version of RN.

Expert's comments needed here to save time of developers. Thanks

Comment: Get any Solution?

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately, there isn't a single repo that is up to date and maintains by the community as far as I know. That's why your options are limited.

**Utilize PayPal APIs**

PayPal has various APIs for different use cases that you can pick up without worrying about the SDK itself. They give you lots of those functionalities, sure it might not be smooth as the SDK itself, but it can solve your problem, nicely.

In case you are developing for both mobile and the web, you can use your APIs for both of them. Becuase they do not depend on the specific platform.

**Solution**

My solution for this is pretty straightforward. Do not use the PayPal SDK if you don't want to mess with Native functionality and not exactly sure why you need it. PayPal has a various set of APIs that you can use on your server side or [client side](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/) without touching the native code. Here I give you a simple scenario that using ExpressCheckout APIs and handle on the server side.

For all below steps, you can use PHP, Node or any other server-side languages. I only briefly tell you the steps and the rest are on you!

**1. Create an access token for your transaction.** Follow below link for details.

> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call

**2. Create a payment transaction.** You need to pass your payment details such as currency and total amount. In this step, you can pass your 'return_url' and cancel_url too. Make sure to attach your order id or order code to both of them, so you can track the orders when either of them triggered and change your order status accordingly.

> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-payments-api/create-express-checkout-payments/

**3. Send the payment URL to React Native and load it by WebView.** 
In this Step, you can use the WebView component in React Native and load the PayPal URL inside. Later for checking whether the payment is done, you can either use a throttling function or use other alternatives such as WebSocket. The goal here is to know whether the transaction is done or canceled.

When the payment is done. get rid of the WebView and redirect the user to thank you page and any other things you need to do after the user payment is done.

There might be more elegant ways to do this, but I believe for simple scenarios (or even more!) this is sufficient.

Comment: Can you share one sample app which is doing such kind of stuff? Also Can we have only client side impl and for server side use https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js for react-native?

Comment: Can you please tell me how can you track the payment status in webview with websocket? @DanialKalbasi

Comment: @DanialKalbasi How about 3DS payment? how to implement 3DS? is the URL provided to **WebView** will redirect the user to Bank 3DS page to complete payment?

Answer (score 4):

As Danial suggested above, if you do not want your app do be dependant on third party react native libraries then try integrating paypal with a WebView wrapper. 
Here is how I did it [Integrating Paypal in your react native app](https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/integrating-paypal-in-your-react-native-app-4dcf89e11dd)

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoZzt.png)
link=
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paypal-lib
Use this Library for React Native Application It's very simple to implements.follow these steps for implementation.