# React Native Paypal Integration For Android

Tags: react-native, paypal

I want to integrate Paypal SDK into an android application that I’ve created with React Native. I have used [sharafat/react-native-paypal](https://github.com/sharafat/react-native-paypal) which is forked from [MattFoley/react-native-paypal](https://github.com/MattFoley/react-native-paypal) (MattFoley’s package is not updated anymore). It works on emulator without a problem, but when I create an apk, the app won’t open.

We want either an easy solution to the error in our current application

Comment: Can you paste the log that you get in your adb logcat ? That should help you debug this

Comment: you can also use Paypal APIs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643092/paypal-payment-integration-for-react-native-with-latest-lib-android-ios/